# Prove that $\Vert A \Vert \le \dfrac{1}{1-2\varepsilon} \sup_{x \in \mathcal{N},\ y\in \mathcal{M}} \langle Ax,y\rangle$

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, linear-transformations, normed-spaces, inner-products

**Problem.** Let $A = (a_{ij})$, $1\le i \le m$, $1\le j \le n$ and $\varepsilon \in (0,1/2) $. Let $\mathcal{N}$ be an $\varepsilon$-net of $S^{n-1}$ and $\mathcal{M}$ be an $\varepsilon$-net of $S^{m-1}$ ($S^{m-1}$ and $S^{n-1}$ are unit spheres). Prove that

\begin{align*}
            \sup_{x \in \mathcal{N},\ y \in \mathcal{M}} \langle Ax,y\rangle  \le \Vert A \Vert \le \dfrac{1}{1-2\varepsilon} \sup_{x \in \mathcal{N}, y \in \mathcal{M}} \langle Ax,y \rangle.
\end{align*}

**My attempt:** Let $x \in \mathcal{N}$ and $y \in \mathcal{M}$. Hence, there exist $x' \in S^{n-1}$, $y' \in S^{m-1}$ such that
\begin{align*}
    & \Vert x - x' \Vert_2 \le \varepsilon,\\
    & \Vert y - y' \Vert_2 \le \varepsilon.
\end{align*}
Hence, we have
\begin{align*}
    \vert \langle Ax,y \rangle - \langle Ax',y'\rangle \vert 
    & = \vert \langle Ax,y\rangle - \langle Ax',y\rangle + \langle Ax',y\rangle - \langle Ax',y'\rangle\\
    & = \vert \langle A(x-x'),y\rangle + \langle Ax',y-y'\rangle \vert\\
    & = \vert \langle A(x-x'),y\rangle \vert + \vert \langle Ax',y-y'\rangle \vert \tag{triangle inequality}\\
   & = \Vert A (x-x') \Vert_2 \cdot \Vert y \Vert +  \Vert Ax'\Vert_2 \cdot \Vert y-y' \Vert_2 \tag{Cauchy-Schwarz inequality}\\
   & \le \Vert A \Vert \cdot \Vert x-x' \Vert_2 \cdot \Vert y \Vert_2 + \Vert A \Vert \cdot \Vert x' \Vert \cdot y-y'\Vert \\
   & \le \Vert A\Vert \varepsilon + \Vert A \Vert \varepsilon = 2\varepsilon \Vert A \Vert.
\end{align*}

Now I am stuck here. I would like to know if you can give me some ideas to deal with the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sketch of one approach. First, show that given $\alpha \in (1,\infty )$, there are $x_{0}\in S^{n-1}$ and $y_{0}\in S^{m-1}$ such that $\|A\| \leq \alpha \langle A(x_{0}), y_{0}\rangle $. Second, given $x'\in \mathcal{N}$ and $y'\in\mathcal{M}$ such that $\|x' - x_{0}\| \leq \varepsilon$ and $\|y' - y_{0}\| \leq \varepsilon$, modify the work from the inequality in your answer to show that $\langle A(x_{0}), y_{0}\rangle \leq \langle A(x'), y'\rangle + 2\varepsilon \|A\|$. After that, use the previously obtained estimates to show that

$$(1-2\varepsilon\alpha )\|A\| \leq \sup_{x\in\mathcal{N}, y\in\mathcal{M}}\langle A(x), y\rangle .$$

The result follows from taking the supremum over all $\alpha \in (1,\infty )$.

Comment: Thank you a lot. Could you please clarify the first step a little bit more?

Comment: @TungNguyen No problem. If $\alpha >1$, you can find some $x_{0}\in S^{n-1}$ such that $\|A\| \leq \alpha \|A(x_{0})\|$. For if you were not able to do this, you can show that it obtains a contradiction with the definition of $\|A\|$. Then it is possible to choose some $y_{0}\in S^{m-1}$ such that $\|A(x_{0})\| = \langle A(x_{0}), y_{0}\rangle$.

Comment: I wonder if the point $x_0$ you are mentioning is the singular vector corresponding to the singular value of $A$.

Comment: I have finished the proof of the problem based on your hints. Once again, thank youu! ^^

Comment: @TungNguyen Yes, there would be a point $x_{0}\in S^{n-1}$ where $\|A\| = \|A(x_{0})\|$. I phrased this in a way that allows the proof to be extended to inner product spaces, where the supremum is not always attained.