# Is $\sup_{x \in S^{n-1}} \vert \langle Ax,x\rangle\vert$ equal to $\sup_{x,y \in S^{n-1}} \langle Ax,y\rangle$ if $A$ is symmetric

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, hilbert-spaces, inner-products

**Problem:** Let $A = (a_{ij})$ be an $n\times n$ matrix. The spectral norm of $A$ is defined as
$$\Vert A \Vert = \sup_{x,y \in S^{n-1}} \langle Ax,y\rangle.$$

If $A$ is symmetric, I wonder this norm can be rewritten as
$$\Vert A \Vert =  \sup_{x \in S^{n-1}} \vert \langle Ax,x\rangle\vert.$$

Comment: I am not so sure that the bot was right to validate my suggestion of duplicate.

Comment: @AnneBauval Yeah, it looks similar but still a little bit different. Do you have any idea about what happens if $A$ is symmetric?

Comment: (and real): To prove these two sups are equal, I would express both in some orthonormal basis of eigen vectors, and by Cauchy-Schwarz, the first one can be restricted to $y=Ax/\|Ax\|$

Comment: @AnneBauval In this case, the considered operator norm is indeed spectral norm since I used the $l_2$ norm.

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1481615) is another proof that your two sups are equal.

Comment: @AnneBauval I wonder if $A$ is not positive in general. I ask this question because I need to show the following inequality in the case of $m=n$ and $A$ is symmetric.
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4860850/prove-that-vert-a-vert-le-dfrac11-2-varepsilon-sup-x-in-mathcaln?rq=1

Comment: The 3 proofs provided (one in my comment above and two in the linked post) do not require $A$ positive. Only self-adjoint. But this (proof that if $A$ is symmetric then your first sup, i.e. $\|A\|$, is equal to your second one) has nothing to do with your other post, which only deals with the first one.

Comment: @AnneBauval I have deleted my comment. Thank you a lot.